# Why does indexOf method of ArrayList work?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

Please consider the following code (Its quite simple)

```
public class Main {

    public static class A{
        int id;

        public A(final int id){
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if(obj instanceof A){
                final A a = (A) obj;
                return id == a.id;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<A> items = new ArrayList<A>();
        items.add(new A(0));
        items.add(new A(1));

        final Object obj = new A(1);
        System.out.println(items.indexOf(obj));
    }
}
```

When I run this code, `1` will be logged in the console. In my opinion it shouldn't be `1` rather it should be `-1`. I've looked into the `indexOf` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#229). Exactly copy/paste from there:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As we know when my code wants to be run the `else` segment of the above code starts to execute. And as you can see in there, statement `o.equals(elementData[i])` will be executed. So far everything is okay and I have no problems

**My Problem**

Type of variable `o` in the above method is `Object` and when we call `equals` method of it, In my opinion `equals` method of a generic Object will be executed, In the other side I've look at `equals` method of Object [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#150). I copy/paste it here:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Now, in the for-loop at `indexOf` method, It shouldn't any item be matched with `o` object because there is no item in the array which is equal to `o` object, in `==` point of view

Now I wonder how is output of my code equals to `1`. Can any one please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *static* type of `obj` is `Object` but the *runtime* type is `A`.

Since all methods in Java are [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function), it doesn't matter what the static type is. It's the runtime type of the callee that will determine which method is called. In this case the runtime type is `A` thus `A.equals` is called.

Analogously the snippet below calls `String.toString` rather than `Object.toString` because the runtime type of `o` is `String`.

```
Object o = "Hello";
System.out.println(o.toString());

// Prints "Hello" and not something like "java.lang.String@15db9742"
```

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing the *compile-time* type of a variable with the *execution-time* type of its value.

The `A.equals` method will be called rather than `Object.equals` because of overriding - the *execution-time* type is used to determine which override of a method is used. If this weren't the case, custom equality overrides could *never* be used by `ArrayList.indexOf`. Don't forget that the declared type of `obj` is entirely unknown to the `ArrayList.indexOf` code. All it has is the *value* of the `o` parameter - which is a reference to an instance of `A`.

It's really important to differentiate between compile-time types (which are used for overloading, checking what members are available etc) and the values at execution-time (which are used for overriding, `instanceof` etc).

Comment: I don't think the confusion is due to `obj instanceof A` evaluating to true (even though `obj` is an `Object`) but rather that `A.equals` is called (and not `Object.equals`) as `o` has static type `Object`. (Why else would OP bring up the implementation of `Object.equals`?)

Comment: Thanks Jon, your answer was very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here: "In my opinion equals method of a generic Object will be executed, ". Although the specified type of "o" is "Object", it still has an actual type of "A". Meaning, that o.equals(...) will in fact invoke A.equals, rather than Object.equals.

Answer (score 0):

`A` extends `Object` and you have overridden its `equals(Object)` method. Therefore, via the `Object` reference, you see its methods that it inherits from `Object`, but calling it like so will call the `equals` method you provided.

What you claimed would happen would happen only if your `equals(Object)` method called `super.equals(Object)`.

If this wasn't the case, heterogenous collections and inheritance would be useless, and OOP would go down the drain.